# How to make user browser download gmail attachment directly from GMAIL?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

How to make user browser download gmail attachment directly from GMAIL when accessing 3rd party web app which can get the attachment information using gmail api?

Here's the scenario: 
1) There's web application with server side code that can fetch emails using GMail API. 
2) If the message has attachment and the user clicks download attachment button I want the user browser to download the attachment directly from GMail without having the web app download it first to server and then send it to the user browser.

So basicly I'm asking how to create URL that points to gmail and makes the user browser get the attachment from there. Does this make any sense?

We can assume the user browser can/is authenticated to GMail.

Tried finding possible solutions but failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to make an URL to an attachment using the Gmail API. CORS is enabled however, so you could use the `access_token` on the front end to download the attachment right away, but exposing the `access_token` to the client comes with a set of security risks you will have to take into consideration.